# Getting wrong types in Nuxt 3, but just in VSCode

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, nuxt.js, volar

I'm building a blog page using Nuxt 3, @nuxtjs/sanity and I got this Typescript error.

```
interface Post {
  _id: string;
  _type: "post";
  _createdAt: string;
  title?: string;
  slug: Slug;
  author: string;
  authorPic: ImageAsset
  excerpt?: string;
  mainImage?: ImageAsset;
  body: PortableTextBlock[];
}


// fetching
const { data } = await useSanityQuery<Post>(query)
```

```
// reference
<BlogCard
  v-for="post in data"
  :blog="{
    title: post['title'],
    slug: post['slug'],
    dateCreated: post['dateCreated'],
    author: post['author'],
    image: post['imageUrl']
   }"
/>
```

Here's that VSCode Intellisense told me:

```
// type i got from VSCode intellisense
const post: string | Slug | ImageAsset | PortableTextBlock[] | undefined
```

Here's what it should be:

```
// type i expected
const post: {
  _id: string;
  _type: "post";
  _createdAt: string;
  title?: string;
  slug: Slug;
  author: string;
  authorPic: ImageAsset
  excerpt?: string;
  mainImage?: ImageAsset;
  body: PortableTextBlock[];
}
```

(Posts is, and suppose to be an array of Post type)

[type error at the reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWzth.png)

> 'post' is possibly 'undefined'.ts(18048)
> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"title"' can't be used to index type 'string | Slug | ImageAsset | PortableTextBlock[]'.
> Property 'title' does not exist on type 'string | Slug | ImageAsset | PortableTextBlock[]'.ts(7053)

I hate to say this on StackOverflow, but it was working fine without an error yesterday.

This seems to be a problem only in the IDE though, as the dev server output works fine.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBmCz.png)

I'm using

- VSCodium 1.85.1 on Windows 11
- Volar 1.8.25
- Typescript 5.3.2

I've tried the followings:

- Removing `node_modules` and `.nuxt` directory and reinstalling using `pnpm install`
- Changing Volar's version to older version (I was using 1.8.25)

Comment: You need to add the code. Not images.